Where can I see if a venue on OpenReview is configured to make paper submissions public during the review process?
Where can I see if a venue on OpenReview is configured to make paper submissions public during the review process? I have access to the Program Chairs Console. I looked at the Full Venue Configuration  but I couldn't find the information.

Here's the field in the Full Venue Configuration:


Submission Readers: Assigned program committee (assigned reviewers, assigned area chairs, assigned senior area chairs if applicable)


Related field:


Withdrawn Submissions Visibility: No, withdrawn submissions should not be made public.


The Submission Readers can be changed in the ‘Post Submission’ form:

